# Listing files with same extension using google drive sdk

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have been trying to integrate google drive sdk in my android application. It all seems to work fine but now i have a requirement where in i would like to list out all the files with the same extension. For example I would like to get a list of all JPG files that the user might have saved to his google drive.
For doing this i tried to use the following

```
FileList temp = service.files().list().setQ("title contains 'jpg'").execute();
```

But this does not return me anything.

On the other hand if i replace jpg with one of the words in the file name then it seems to work fine. So strangely a search on extension is not working while a search on the main name seems to work

Is this functionality broken with the drive sdk or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment left by Burcu Dogan it is clear that at this point of time querying based on file extensions is not possible. Will have to wait for an update to the google drive sdk to include such functionality.

Putting this out as a note to help anyone who might be facing a simialr issue and looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive determines file types based on their mimeType attribute, not their extension. Instead of looking at the file name, try something like:

```
FileList temp = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'image/jpeg'").execute();
```

Comment: That is correct but what if i have to look for files which have a custom extension generated by some application which the user might have uploaded?

Comment: We dont have any means of support for `ext` querying at the moment. Although we're planning to fix it in the future.

Comment: @Jay Lee if incase we want to fetch out the list of files of multiple mimetypes let say we want files of application/pdf and image/jpg , then how will we pass both mimetype in setQ parameters